# Brokering IO requests in a static class

Tags: c#, asynchronous, static, async-await

I have a single, static `Broker` class with a set of 'drivers' that make network IO requests to equipment. I have instances of a `Device` class that call it to read data from the equipment via the drivers.

The broker exists to serve requests by the other classes because we have a limited number of concurrent connections we can make.

The problem comes in when `Devices` share the same driver type and make overlapping calls for data. The driver is a shared resource and can't service both at the same time.

Here's a naive implementation (not running, just how I envision it working):

```
    public static void ReadDataItem(DriverType driverType, string ip, DataItemAddress address, Action<IList<ushort>> callback)
    {
        //Can return one of three driver instances, depending on type
        var driver = RetrieveDriver(driverType);

        if (!driver.Initialized)
        {
            //NOTE: Make sure connection is set up to correct PLC
        }

        Task<IList<ushort>> result = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => driver.ReadDataItem(address));
        callback(result.Result);
    }
```

Obviously, if two Devices call with the same driver, there's no mechanism to 'queue' up the request.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can make the calling clients 'wait their turn' for the data?

Comment: You should return a `Task<T>`, not accept a callback.

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ComparingTwoTechniquesInNETAsynchronousCoordinationPrimitives.aspx

Comment: @SLaks Yeah, I had Task<IList<ushort>> originally but figured I may be able to store the callback to a reference to callback in a queue or something for later... As for Shanselman's blog post, not entirely sure I get what you're suggesting.

Comment: It sounds like you want an async lock.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use [`SemaphoreSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this:

```
static readonly s_semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

public static async Task<IList<ushort>> ReadDataItem(DriverType driverType, string ip, DataItemAddress address, Action<IList<ushort>> callback)
{
    using (var driver = RetrieveDriver(driverType))
    {
        if (!driver.Initialized)
        {
            //NOTE: Make sure connection is set up to correct PLC
        }

        // you can use different semaphores,
        // depending on the type of the driver
        await s_semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            return await ask.Factory.StartNew(() => driver.ReadDataItem(address));
        }
        finally
        {
            s_semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may have a look at DataFlowBlock which handle this for you. 
Here an example doing what I assume you want to do. The core idea is on BufferBlock and ActionBlock.
BufferBlock will queue messages, while ActionBlock will deques and perform operation on these messages (ie-read data from device in your case).

Hope this help.

```
public  class MultiplexerBase<T> : CommunicationObject, IMultiplexer<T>
    where T: IMessage
{
    BufferBlock<T> _buffer;
    ActionBlock<T> _dispatcher;

    IOutputChannel<T> _channel;

    public MultiplexerBase(IOutputChannel<T> p_output)
    {
        _channel = p_output;
    }

    public IOutputChannel<T> UnderlyingChannel { get { return _channel; } }

    public Task SendAsync(T p_frame)
    {
        return _buffer.SendAsync(p_frame);
    }

    public Task SendAsync(T p_frame, CancellationToken p_ct)
    {
        return _buffer.SendAsync(p_frame,p_ct);
    }

    protected override void OnOpen()
    {
        _buffer = new BufferBlock<T>();
        _dispatcher = new ActionBlock<T>(m => _channel.Send(m));
        _buffer.LinkTo(_dispatcher);
    }

    protected override void OnClose()
    {
        _buffer.Complete();
        _buffer = null;
        _dispatcher = null;
    }
```

}

Comment: There is no need for that `BufferBlock` here, `ActionBlock` has its own queue.

Comment: @svick thanks for the great advice. Where do you get this information ?? I do not found the code on http://referencesource.microsoft.com/...